# Referencing submodule from git repository results in error when initializing module during GitLab CI/CD execution

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-aws, gitlab-ci-runner

I reference my module as:

```
source =  "git::https://gitlab.com/dash-infrastructure.git//modules/lambda-apigw-api"
```

Terraform plan in my CI/CD passess fine. However, in the terraform apply stage, I get the following error:

```
│ Error: Failed to download module
│ 
│   on main-lambda-apigw-from-module.tf line 1:
│    1: module "lambda_apigw_module" {
│ 
│ Could not download module "lambda_apigw_module"
│ (main-lambda-apigw-from-module.tf:1) source code from
│ "git::https://gitlab.com/dash-infrastructure.git":
│ error downloading
│ 'https://gitlab.com/dash-infrastructure.git':
│ /usr/bin/git exited with 1: error: pathspec 'master' did not match any
│ file(s) known to git
```

Branch 'master' doesn't even exist in the repository of my module. Any idea what could be the issue?

I am expecting the apply to download my module from the git repo. I tried specifying the ref to my only and default branch - main, even specifying the commit hash with:

`source =  "git::https://gitlab.com/dash-infrastructure.git//modules/lambda-apigw-api/?ref=main"`

But did not help, still same error.

### EDIT - RESOLVED

Matt was right - the pipeline executing workflow was indeed the issue. I unintentionally included all 'untracked' files as artifacts of the GitLab CI/CD stage 'terraform plan', which caused this discrepancy. When adding only the artifacts I needed (plans directory), this problem was fixed:

```
plan lambda develop:
  stage: deploy_lambda
  tags:
    - dash
  needs: 
    - job: build lambda develop
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - cd ./backend/lambda/infrastructure/nonprod
    - mkdir plans
    - *terraform-init-nonprod
    - terraform plan -out plans/plan
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - backend/lambda/infrastructure/nonprod/plans/*
```

Comment: I'm thinking since there are no references after the module name, it is by default using the master branch. Are you using module versioning maybe or a different branch name?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you would need to specify the git reference which can be a branch, tag, commit sha, etc. Assuming from the latter portion of the question that you intend to reference a branch `main`:

```
source = "git::https://gitlab.com/dash-infrastructure.git?ref=main"
```

and the `main` branch of the git remote repository would be retrieved through `terraform init`. More information can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#selecting-a-revision) which also links to git reference documentation.

Additionally:

> Terraform plan in my CI/CD passess fine. However, in the terraform apply stage, I get the following error:

This heavily implies there are also issues in the pipeline code executing the workflow portion, and so there may need to be a followup question around that.

Answer (score 0):

Matt was right - the pipeline executing workflow was indeed the issue. I unintentionally included all 'untracked' files as artifacts of the GitLab CI/CD stage 'terraform plan', which caused this discrepancy. When adding only the artifacts I needed (plans directory), this problem was fixed:

```
plan lambda develop:
  stage: deploy_lambda
  tags:
    - dash
  needs: 
    - job: build lambda develop
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - cd ./backend/lambda/infrastructure/nonprod
    - mkdir plans
    - *terraform-init-nonprod
    - terraform plan -out plans/plan
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - backend/lambda/infrastructure/nonprod/plans/*
```